# UDP traffic between two seperate virtual machines?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp

I'm making a chat app in python that runs directly on UDP to get more familiar with networking, and I'm just fixing up my connection protocol, and I spun up a fresh VM behind a proxy to test if the python script would accept the UDP traffic from an external IP, and, nothing.

The short and sweet version of my serverside code: (server.py)

```
import socket

localIP = ''
localPort = 1993
bufferSize = 1024

UDPServerSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPServerSocket.bind((localIP, localPort))
print("UDP server up and listening")

while (True):

  bytesAddressPair = UDPServerSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)

  message = bytesAddressPair[0]
  address = bytesAddressPair[1]


  clientMsg = "Message from Client:{}".format(message)
  clientIP = "Client IP Address:{}".format(address)
  print(clientMsg)
  print(clientIP)
```

My client.py networking stuff:

```
import socket

UDPClientSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
socket.setdefaulttimeout(10)
#I know this IP is a placeholder, it's not that way in my actual code
serverAddressPort = ("1.1.1.1", 1993)

bufferSize = 1024

def recvUDP():
  try:
    response = UDPClientSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
    return response
  except Exception as e:
    choice = confirm(
      f"Exception '{e}' occured while awaiting server response. Try again?")
    if choice:
      response = recvUDP()


def getUDP(message):
  UDPClientSocket.sendto(str.encode(message), serverAddressPort)
  try:
    response = UDPClientSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
    while response is None:
      time.sleep(0.1)
      response = recvUDP()
    return response
  except Exception as e:
    choice = confirm(
      f"Exception '{e}' occured while awaiting server response. Try again?")
    if choice:
      response = getUDP(message)

def connect():

  response = getUDP("initial")

  if response is None:
    sys.exit()

  print("Initial packet recieved")
  
  
connect()
```

I can't seem to get any sort of communication between the two machines directly over UDP, but I did try a simple `nc -L -p 1993` from the server machine and `curl` from the client machine, which had the packet recieved.
When I tried to bind it to the public IP, it said that the socket module was unable to bind to the given IP.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: what is the server machine's IP, is it the public one? The thing about this private IP, public IP, NAT stuff is that it's hidden from the machine that has the private IP. That machine *thinks* the private IP is its real IP.

Answer (score 0):

You've got several things going on; First off your syntax on nc looks weird, it should be something like:

```
# Listen on UDP port <port> 
nc -u -l <port>

# Connect to <port>
nc -u localhost <port>
```

Secondly, your socket code mostly looks good, but you are trying to connect to 1.1.1.1, which probably isn't your computer. Have you tried to connect to your computer? Typically that would just be localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Localhost works fine, it's just when I spin up a seperate VM that it refuses to do anything over UDP

Comment: @MrToenails First check that nc works, if it does then you have network connectivity and your application should work.

Comment: @CharlesS `#I know this IP is a placeholder, it's not that way in my actual code`

Comment: @CharlesS the netcat works when I listen on port 80 and use `curl` from the client machine, and I can reach external addresses  using `wget` and `curl` just fine from both machines.